# How can i resolve an already running promise in my promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

this is my first question here.

I have this code:

```
const work = async () => {
  const file = new lineByLine(filename);
  let line;

  while (line = file.next()) {
    const worker = await getIdleWorker()
    worker.assign({documentId: line.toString()})
    worker.work()
  }
}


// todo: I need time for resolve other promises meanwhile this is executed.
const getIdleWorker = async () => {
  while (true) {
    for (let i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
      const worker = workers[i]

      if (worker.isReady()) {
        return worker;
      }


    // Solution: give time to resolve other promises.
    await sleep(10).milliseconds();
    }
  }
}
```

The worker.work method set a property `running` to true, do a job and when is ready, change the same property `running` to false. Meanwhile, the getIdleWorker() search for a worker which has that property `running` to false, this method wait forever until a idle worker is found.

The problem is never find an idle worker, i suppose because the promise worker.work never get resolved because the main thread is stuck in the getIdleWorker.

Which is the best solution for a problem like this? I don't care if i have to change the design completely.

Thanks !

Comment: await getIdleWorker() blocks the thread until it returns. If it's waiting for a worker that matches your conditions it will never reach worker.work();

The question is why doesn't getIdleWorker() returning anything? You should have a pool of workers set to false.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm trying by now with 1 worker concurrency, and the first is time is resolved, but the second time no, because as you said, the thread is blocked. I'm thinking which is the better way for this cases. Thanks !

Comment: Could you add the code of `getIdleWorker` function?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Updated ! Thanks.

Comment: In that case work() should finish and then it can get the next worker. Why isn't work() finishing? Show the code.

Comment: Show the worker.work() code

Comment: I resolved it adding a sleep line, recommended by @ManuelSpigolon

Comment: @JaviercitoIgnacio Please undo the edit to the question and instead [post the solution as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This implementation should work, it checks every second for a free worker and if it found it, the worker is returned back.

```js
const getIdleWorker = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const findFreeWorker = () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
        const worker = workers[i]
        if (worker.isReady()) {
          return worker;
        }
      }
      return null
    }

    const searchFor = setInterval(() => {
      const freeWorker = findFreeWorker()
      if (freeWorker) {
        clearInterval(searchFor)
        resolve(freeWorker)
      }
    }, 1000)
  })
}
```

The problem was the `while (true) {` that was blocking the event loop so Node.js was stuck executing that piece of code forever, adding `async` was trying to return only a Promise, but the code was in an infinite loop.

[Here](https://www.nearform.com/blog/javascript-promises-the-definitive-guide/) you can find a good article to understand better the async pattern of Node.js